# my font's does not render on firefox as well as it is on google chrome

Tags: javascript, css

i use @font-family for my special font style and it works properly on my google chrome browser , but on Firefox it is not... actually it's Rendering Issue: Fonts no longer smoothed in Firefox ...

who i can to fix this problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <style>
  @font-face{
   font-family: example;
   src:url(./fonts/rasmi.otf);
  }
  .myFont{
   font-family: example;
   font-size: 40px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p class="myFont">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex aspernatur debitis esse unde quia delectus natus, atque nesciunt optio consequuntur ducimus facere magnam, corporis eligendi totam molestias nostrum a earum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show us the relevant code. Different browsers support different font formats.

Comment: Probably is the font format as said Scott Marcus. Take a look at this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: @ScottMarcus above code is a sample that shows how i use new font-family , and it is working good in both chrome & firefox... but in my primary code, i was using that style & i han't same result...   in firefox it seem  a little pixel and not smooth (like in chrome)

Comment: @sheida As I mentioned, different browsers recognize different fonts. You need other formats for it to work in other browsers. Visit fontsquirrel.com

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

on your body.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

To the body in your CSS to get clean antialiasing in Firefox.

Comment: unfortunately it don't make a diffrence

Comment: Sorry, you need to include -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; for non Mac clients.